# Entity relationships code first approach

Tags: sql, entity-framework-6, system-design

I am building Patient Appointment booking system and using the code first approach of the entity framework. I have designed the models and their relationships. Could somebody let me know if there is anything incorrect ?

I am assuming following are the relationships. Please correct me if I am wrong

1. One Patient can have many appointments and one appointment can belong to only one patient. Hence Patient has one to many relationship with appointments.
2. One Practioner can have many appointments and one appointment can belong to only one practioner. Hence Practioner has one to many relationship with appointments.
3. One Practioner can have many PractionerTypes(E.g Doctor,Nurse) and one PractionerType can belong to only one Practioner. Hence Practioner has one to many relationship with PractionerTypes.
4. One Appointment can have many AppointmentTypes(E.g Standard,Special) and one AppointmentTypes can belong to only one Appointment . Hence Appointment has one to many relationship with AppointmentTypes .
5. One Practioner can have many PractitionerAvailableHours and one PractitionerAvailableHours can belong to only one Practioner

I am bit confused after seeing this article http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

As per this article, when you are doing a one to many relationship , you need to define the property of the many class in the one class and have a collection property of one class in the many class. In their example. Student is the one class and Standard is the many class. The student has virtual property method of the standard class and the standard class has the virtual collection property of the student class
In my design, Its just the other way round. Assuming Patient and Appointments have one to many relationship

Considering the above the enity design would look as follows

**Appointment**

```
 public class Appointment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public DateTime Time { get; set; }

        public string Note { get; set; }

        public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }

        public virtual Practioner Practioner { get; set; }

        public int PatientId { get; set; }

        public int PractionerId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AppointmentType> AppointmentType { get; set; }
    }
```

**AppointmentType**

```
   public class AppointmentType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Appointment Appointment { get; set; }
        public int AppointmentId { get; set; }
    }
```

**Patient**

```
  public class Patient
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        public char Gender { get; set; }

        public string Phone { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }

        public string State { get; set; }

        public string Postcode { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

    }
```

**Practioner**

```
  public class Practioner
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PractitionerAvailableHours> PractionerAvailableHours { get; set; }
    }
```

**PractionerType**

```
public class PractionerType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int PractionerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Practioner Practioner { get; set; }
}
```

**PractitionerAvailableHours**

```
public class PractitionerAvailableHours
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Practioner Practioner { get; set; }

    public int PractionerId { get; set; }

    public DateTime AvailableDate { get; set; }

    public int AvailableHours { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sounds correct to me. I would maybe, even if not used, make Practitioner / Appointment relationship as many to many. I would not be surprised that in practice, like for global medical decision with the patient, you could have this case where several Practitioners go to same appointment. Just in case I would let that possibility opened.

Comment: Is the relation between Appointment and AppointmentType and Practioner and PractionerType correct ?

Comment: I don't see any problem there, you will have to mark the foreign keys for the relation with code attribute like this: In `PractionerType` On `Practioner` property add `[ForeignKey("PractionerId")]`. Same for `AppointmentType` class. You will have to do so a bit everywhere actually :)

Comment: refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx for more informations on EF Code First Data Annotation

Comment: I didn't know that you need to add foreign key attribute . I thought entity framework was smart to understand just by naming convention. For eg in the appointments table practitionerid and patientid would be understood to be foreign key constraints

Comment: I am using entity framework 6

Comment: Most of the time it's smart enought to figure out by itself, I think with your very straight forward naming conventions it will be ok

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131245/discussion-between-tom-and-piou).

Comment: I am bit confused after seeing this article entityframeworktutorial.net/…
As per this article, when you are doing a one to many relationship , you need to define the property of the many class in the one class and have a collection property of one class in the many class. In their example. Student is the one class and Standard is the many class. The student has virtual property method of the standard class and the standard class has the virtual collection property of the student class
In my design, Its just the other way round. Assuming Patient and Appointments have one to many relationship

Comment: You missunderstood I think, a Standard has many Students, exactly like in your example. The example is not cristal clear though.

Comment: In case of Appointment and AppointmentType, dont you think the AppointmentTypeId should be AppointmentTable rather than AppointmentId be in AppointmentType table